# merge two different arrays having different object types into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapreduce, mapping

I want to merge two different arrays having different object types into one.

Suppose I have one array as:

```
var column = [
  {
    "href": "./?course=13&sort=firstname&silast=all&sifirst=all",
    "title": null
  },
  {
    "href": undefined,
    "title": undefined
  },
  {
    "href": "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/questionnaire/view.php?id=304",
    "title": "Survey on student familiarity with the online learning platform"
  },
  {
    "href": "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/assign/view.php?id=307",
    "title": "update your profile"
  }
]
```

and another array as:

```
var obj = [
  {
    name: "POD DLK",
    profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=217&course=103"
  },
  {
    name: "BGC DO",
    profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=218&course=103"
  },
  {
    name: "CAD SG",
    profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=219&course=103"
  },
  {
    name: "BON DTH",
    profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=207&course=103"
  }
]
```

I had tried one using:

```
const mergedArray = [ ...column, ...obj]
console.log(mergedArray)
```

But this created a separate object in a **mergedArray**.

However, I want to merge the first object from **obj** to the first object in **column**.

Expected output:

```
[{
  href: "./?course=13&amp;sort=firstname&amp;silast=all&amp;sifirst=all",
  title: null,
  name: "POD DLK",
  profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=217&course=103"
}, {
  href: undefined,
  title: undefined,
  name: "BGC DO",
  profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=218&course=103"
}, {
  href: "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/questionnaire/view.php?id=304",
  title: "Survey on student familiarity with the online learning platform",
  name: "CAD SG",
  profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=219&course=103"
}, {
  href: "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/assign/view.php?id=307",
  title: "update your profile",
  name: "BON DTH",
  profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=207&course=103"
}]
```

Comment: You're looking for `zipWith`

Comment: Do you have any criteria how to merge them? Only by index in array?

Comment: just by index. don't have any criteria.

Comment: try to the use of index based loop. as like `lst.push(combine(obj[idx], obj[idx]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to merge by same index.

```js
const
    column = [{ href: "./?course=13&sort=firstname&silast=all&sifirst=all", title: null }, { href: undefined, title: undefined }, { href: "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/questionnaire/view.php?id=304", title: "Survey on student familiarity with the online learning platform" }, { href: "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/assign/view.php?id=307", title: "update your profile" }],
    obj = [{ name: "POD DLK", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=217&course=103" }, { name: "BGC DO", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=218&course=103" }, { name: "CAD SG", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=219&course=103" }, { name: "BON DTH", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=207&course=103" }],
    result = column.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, ...obj[i] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A sightly different approach with reduce

```js
const
    column = [{ href: "./?course=13&sort=firstname&silast=all&sifirst=all", title: null }, { href: undefined, title: undefined }, { href: "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/questionnaire/view.php?id=304", title: "Survey on student familiarity with the online learning platform" }, { href: "http://someurl.edu.lk/mod/assign/view.php?id=307", title: "update your profile" }],
    obj = [{ name: "POD DLK", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=217&course=103" }, { name: "BGC DO", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=218&course=103" }, { name: "CAD SG", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=219&course=103" }, { name: "BON DTH", profile: "http://someurl.edu.lk/user/view.php?id=207&course=103" }],
    result = [column, obj].reduce((r, a) => a.map((o, i) => ({ ...r[i], ...o })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

First a helper function to combine the two arrays pairwise:

```
const zip = (a, b) => {
  const results = [];
  // We'll merge the arrays 'a' and 'b' to the length
  // of the shorter one so we don't get an error if they
  // are different lengths
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); ++i) {
    result.push([a[i], b[i]);
  }
  return results;
};
```

Then merging the pairs of objects becomes a nice one-liner thanks to destructuring:

```
const merged = zip(obj, column).map(([x, y]) => ({ ...x, ...y }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
column.forEach((value, index)=>{Object.assign(value,obj[index])})
```

if you want a new array:

```
column.forEach((value,index)=>{result.push({...value, ...obj[index]})})
```

Comment: This will mutate the original, you might at least warn that it will do so. It will also not work if the arrays are not the same length.

Comment: " I want to merge the first object from obj to the first object in column."

Comment: Stackoverflow is designed to be a repository of knowledge for future seekers as well, and they might be led here but have different requirements than the OP. I'm not saying you're *wrong*, I'm just suggesting that you think of the proverbial children.

Comment: I add a new code that doesn't mutate the original,  thanks for the feedback!